# API tracking code integration in front-end orderdetails (Woocommerce)

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce shop and have a third-party logistic company with API. By this API I will receive a tracking code for the shipped order. I have a php file for getting a tracking code through API. Does anybody know how can I use this file to add this tracking code to the customer's front-end account in Order details section. (The tracking code already appears in order details of admin panel).
The code is:

```
    // print_r($order_ids);die;
$tracking_header = array('Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'apikey:' . API_KEY,);
$tracking_url = "http://";
$tracking = _curlRequest($tracking_url, "POST", json_encode($order_ids), $tracking_header);
$tracking = json_decode($tracking, true);

if ( empty($tracking['data']) || $tracking['code'] == 4  ) {
echo json_encode(array("code" => 4, "msg" => "There are no orders to sync!", "data" => null));return;
} elseif ($tracking['code']) {
echo json_encode(array("code" => 5, "msg" => "There was an error getting the order information!", "data" => null));return;
}
// print_r($tracking);die;
$error = "";
foreach($tracking['data'] as $k=>$v){
$info = json_decode($v['info'],true);
$order_id = $v['order_id'];
if(empty($info)){
continue;
}
if(PREFIX !== 'your prefix' && PREFIX !== ''){
$order_id = substr($order_id,strlen(PREFIX));
}
$sql = "SELECT pm.meta_value as sku FROM {$db_prefix}postmeta as pm WHERE pm.meta_key='_sku' AND pm.post_id in (SELECT oim.meta_value FROM {$db_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta as oim LEFT JOIN {$db_prefix}woocommerce_order_items as oi ON (oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id AND (oim.meta_key='_product_id' OR oim.meta_key='_variation_id')) WHERE oi.order_item_type='line_item' AND oi.order_id ={$order_id})";
$order_sku = $wpdb->get_results($sql,ARRAY_A);
if(!empty($order_sku)){
$new_sku = array();
foreach($order_sku as $val){
if(!empty($val['sku'])){
$new_sku[] = $val['sku'];
}
}
$sync_sku = array();
foreach($info as $ik=>$iv){
if($iv['sku']&& in_array($iv['sku'],$new_sku)){
$sync_sku[] = $iv['sku'];
}
}
if(!empty($sync_sku)){
if($v['shipping_method']){
if(!$wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM {$db_prefix}woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id={$order_id} AND order_item_type='shipping' ", ARRAY_A)){
$data = array(
'order_item_name'=>$v['shipping_method'],
'order_item_type'=>'shipping',
'order_id'=>$order_id
);
$wpdb->insert("{$db_prefix}woocommerce_order_items",$data);
}
}
if($v['tracking_number']){
$order_items = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM {$db_prefix}woocommerce_order_items WHERE order_id={$order_id} AND order_item_type='shipping' ", ARRAY_A);
if($order_items && !$wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM {$db_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta WHERE order_item_id={$order_items['order_item_id']} AND meta_key='tracking_number' ", ARRAY_A)){
$data = array(
            'order_item_id'=>$order_items['order_item_id'],
            'meta_key'=>'tracking_number',
            'meta_value'=>$v['tracking_number']
        );
        if(!$wpdb->insert("{$db_prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta",$data)){
          $error .= $v['order_id'].",";
        }

      }

    }
  }else{

    $error .= $v['order_id'].",";
  }

}    

} 

if($error){
 $errorders = substr($error,0,-1);
echo json_encode(array("code" => 6, "msg" => "Can synchronize but synchronize failed orders:{$errorders}", "data" => null));return;
}

echo json_encode(array("code" => 0, "msg" => "Success", "data" => null));return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

Add the following code in order-details-item.php

```
foreach( $order->get_items('shipping') as $item ){
    echo $item->get_meta('tracking_number');
}
```

But now I have a question, how to make this tracking_number wrapped in URL?
In the following manner that the URL contain https://someaddres&=tracking_number

I resolved this issue.